# Pointer returned by queue can't be dereferenced without segmentation fault

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to write a queue. In order to test it out I've enqueued a couple of values which are pointers to statically allocated stack variables. When I print out the address of the stack variable that's been pushed and the pointer returned by the dequeue (corresponding to the original enqueue for that item), I get what appears to be the same address. When I dereference a pointer to the statically allocated variable (a pointer I create inline using the `&` operator) it prints the value I expect, `10`. But when I deference the pointer returned by the dequeue, which appears to be the same address, that will seg fault. I'm not quite sure what's going on, my understanding of the C memory model can't explain this.

Output

```
Storing item at index 0
Queue (head, tail) = 0, 1
1158904628, 0, 0,
Storing item at index 1
Queue (head, tail) = 0, 2
1158904628, 1158904632, 0,
Storing item at index 2
Queue (head, tail) = 0, 0
1158904628, 1158904632, 1158904636,
---------------------------
Enqueued pointer: 45137b34
Enqueued pointer value: 10
Queue (head, tail) = 1, 0
0, 1158904632, 1158904636,
Dequeued pointer: 45137b34
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Compile with
`gcc -o main queue.c`

Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int *buffer;
    int size;
    int capacity;
    int head;
    int tail;
} Queue;

void queue_init(Queue *queue, int capacity) {
    void *ptr = malloc((sizeof(void*)) * capacity);
    queue->buffer = ptr;
    queue->capacity = capacity;
    queue->size = 0;
    queue->head = 0;
    queue->tail = 0;
}

void* queue_dequeue(Queue *queue) {
    if (queue->size == 0) return NULL;

    void *item = queue->buffer[queue->head];
    queue->buffer[queue->head] = NULL;
    queue->head = (queue->head + 1) % queue->capacity;
    printf("Queue (head, tail) = %d, %d\n", queue->head, queue->tail);
    queue->size--;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("%u, ", queue->buffer[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return item;
}

int queue_enqueue(Queue *queue, void *item) {
    if (queue->size == queue->capacity) return -1;

    printf("Storing item at index %d\n", queue->tail);
    queue->buffer[queue->tail] = item;
    queue->size++;
    queue->tail = (queue->tail + 1) % queue->capacity;
    printf("Queue (head, tail) = %d, %d\n", queue->head, queue->tail);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("%u, ", queue->buffer[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    int a = 10;
    int b = 20;
    int c = 30;

    Queue q;
    queue_init(&q, 3);
    queue_enqueue(&q, &a);
    queue_enqueue(&q, &b);
    queue_enqueue(&q, &c);
    printf("---------------------------\n");

    int *org = &a;
    int *ptr;
    printf("Enqueued pointer: %x\n", org);
    printf("Enqueued pointer value: %i\n", *org);
    ptr = queue_dequeue(&q);
    printf("Dequeued pointer: %x\n", ptr);
    printf("Dequeued pointer value: %i\n", *ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm using a ring buffer as the underlying data structure for the queue with two pointers acting as the head and tail.

Comment: There's no such thing as statically allocated stack variable.

Comment: My mistake, what I mean to say is I am not allocating any of the stored variable pointers dynamically using dynamic allocation.

Comment: Compile with all warnings enabled and treat warnings as errors. You've got plenty.

Comment: Seems like everything in your code expects `buffer` to point to an array of `void *`, except the declaration of `buffer`, which declares that `buffer` points to an array of `int`.

Comment: https://ideone.com/qaMdKD

Comment: @n.m. Thanks for the tip. I had been ignoring some of the warning I was getting naively thinking they could be fixed up later, nor did I use the `Wall` flag this time. I was hoping to be able to use a void pointer to be able to handle multiple data types, but i don't know if that was going to work out. I changed it to the `int ** buffer` (@user3386109) and after fixing some other compiler warning it's no longer seg faulting. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to change `int *` to `void **`, 
otherwise integer space (4bytes) is not enough to save void* (8bytes) 
modified as follows

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    void **buffer;
    int size;
    int capacity;
    int head;
    int tail;
} Queue;

void queue_init(Queue *queue, int capacity) {
    void *ptr = malloc((sizeof(void*)) * capacity);
    queue->buffer = ptr;
    queue->capacity = capacity;
    queue->size = 0;
    queue->head = 0;
    queue->tail = 0;
}

void* queue_dequeue(Queue *queue) {
    if (queue->size == 0) return NULL;

    void *item = queue->buffer[queue->head];
    queue->buffer[queue->head] = NULL;
    queue->head = (queue->head + 1) % queue->capacity;
    printf("Queue (head, tail) = %d, %d\n", queue->head, queue->tail);
    queue->size--;

    for (int i = 0; i < queue->size; i++) {
        printf("%p, ", queue->buffer[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return item;
}

int queue_enqueue(Queue *queue, void *item) {
    if (queue->size == queue->capacity) return -1;

    printf("Storing item at index %d\n", queue->tail);
    queue->buffer[queue->tail] = item;
    queue->size++;
    queue->tail = (queue->tail + 1) % queue->capacity;
    printf("Queue (head, tail) = %d, %d\n", queue->head, queue->tail);

    for (int i = 0; i < queue->size; i++) {
        printf("%p, ", queue->buffer[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    int a = 10;
    int b = 20;
    int c = 30;

    Queue q;
    queue_init(&q, 3);
    queue_enqueue(&q, &a);
    queue_enqueue(&q, &b);
    queue_enqueue(&q, &c);
    printf("---------------------------\n");

    int *org = &a;
    int *ptr;
    printf("Enqueued pointer: %p\n", org);
    printf("Enqueued pointer value: %i\n", *org);
    ptr = queue_dequeue(&q);
    printf("Dequeued pointer: %p\n", ptr);
    printf("Dequeued pointer value: %i\n", *ptr);

    return 0;
}
```